# using '\foreach' loops to draw tikz figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops, draw, tikz-graphdrawing

I am using `\usepackage{tikz}` to draw something using `xyz` coordinates.
I have a bunch of coordinates named `(xyt)` such as (000) (001) (020)...(001)(011) etc, they are created by:

```
\coordinate (ijk) at (i,k,j);
```

e.g.

```
\coordinate (001) at (0,1,0);
```

I want to write a loop to draw something like:

```
\draw (110)--(000)--(011)--(020);
\draw (111)--(001)--(012)--(021);
\draw (112)--(002)--(013)--(022);
etc.
```

Essentially what I want to do is (in python language):

```
for i in range(9):
    j=i+1
    \draw (11i) -- (00i) -- (01j) -- (02i);
```

And I tried:

```
\foreach \time in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{
\draw (11\time) -- (00\time) -- (01{\time+1}) -- (02\time);
}
```

However, Tikz identify `{\time+1}` as `{1+1},{2+1},...` instead of `2,3,...`, while `(00\time)` is causing no problem.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: `foreach \time [evaluate=\time as \suivant using int(\time+1)]{\draw (11\time) -- (00\time) -- (01{\suivant}) -- (02\time);}`

Comment: @AndréC Nice solution. If you write up this comment as a formal answer, I will accept that.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it.

Comment: I just published a response. Is that what you wanted to do? If not exactly that, please specify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of foreach loops increments by 1 implicitly, so it is not necessary to list all integers from `0` to `9`, just write `{0,...,9}`.

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,9}{  };
```

In the loop where you calculate the next integer `\time+1`, since the coordinates go from `(000)` to `(999)` it is mandatory to limit the list which must go from `0` to `8`. Because otherwise we obtain `9+1=10`, which produces an non-existent coordinate `(0110)`.

```
\foreach \time [evaluate=\time as \suivant using int(\time+1)]in {0,...,8}
    \draw (11\time) -- (00\time) -- (01\suivant) -- (02\time);
```

I don't know if that's the result you want to achieve. I tried to understand by sticking back the little pieces of code from your question. I hope that this is convenient for you, otherwise please specify your question.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\foreach \x in {0,...,9}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,9}
        \foreach \z in {0,...,9}
            \coordinate (\x\y\z) at (\x,\y,\z);

\foreach \time [evaluate=\time as \suivant using int(\time+1)]in {0,...,8}
    \draw (11\time) -- (00\time) -- (01\suivant) -- (02\time);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found an easy fix;

It turns out that I just need to use

```
\foreach \time in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{
\draw (1,\time,1) -- (0,\time,0) -- (0,\time+1,1) -- (0,\time,2);
}
```

instead...